# Video player in browser lags, would increasing VGA Memory in BIOS help?

Tags: ubuntu, video, bios, vga

Using Ubuntu 14.04 (but the question is in general) - using a HTML5 video player, the video lags, freezes for a very small amount of time, sometimes, not so often.

Could it help, that I increase the VGA Memory size in the BIOS? Or it isn't related to video lagging in the webbrowser?

Notebook.

Comment: what?  you can't "increse the VGA memory size in the BIOS".  the size of your video ram depends on your GPU.   BTW, slow video playback in the browser probably means a) your machine is too busy, or b) your GPU is under-powered.  If you were using a desktop, it's easy enough to upgrade your video card but as you're using a notebook you are stuck with whatever is built in.   Also, more details are required to answer this question, including: what brand/model of CPU, what brand/model of GPU, how much video RAM, how much system RAM.

Comment: I mean, there is a setting in the BIOS, how much is the VGA memory size, probably it gets from the normal RAM. Type is Lenovo T61!